# Multiple Open Email Items in One Item_Send Sub Issue

Tags: vba, vb.net, email, outlook, outlook-addin

Currently my code checks the email (on the Item_Send Event) to see if it has an attachment and then gives a conditional Form to Encrypt and Send, Send Un-encrypted, or Cancel Send. It also searches for SSN's in the body giving the user the same Form popup. All works as advertised unless the user has two email windows/instances open at the same time. For example if email#1 has an attachment and email#2 is sitting in the background, if I were to try and send email#1 and opt to Cancel Send it goes back to email#1 without sending (as advertised), however, when you go back to email#2 and try to send (that has nothing to do with email#1) it will not send either. I'll show the code below, but I use the "Cancel=True" command to stop the email, but this stops the send operation and the inspector is left open, thus not letting me send any emails that may have been open at that time. Is there any ideas around this? How can I have this Item_Send event only handle the CURRENT Outlook.MailItem instance and not another that may be open at the same time. Thanks! I left alot out of the code, this is just part of the problem I'm having. SSNBtnPress=3 for Cancel=True

```
Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
    ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ItemSend
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Item, Outlook.MailItem)
    If mailItem IsNot Nothing Then
  frm1.ShowDialog()
        If (SSNbtnPress = 1) Then
            mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/x-PII", "Encryptclicked")
            If RegexObj1.IsMatch(mailItem.Body) Then
                mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003", 3)
                Cancel = False
            ElseIf RegexObj1.IsMatch(mailItem.Subject) Then
                mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003", 3)
                Cancel = False
            Else
                mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003", 3)
                Dim addToBody As String = "Test" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + mailItem.Body
                Dim addtoSubject As String = "Test " + mailItem.Subject
                mailItem.Subject = addtoSubject
                mailItem.Body = addToBody
                Cancel = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If (SSNbtnPress = 2) Then
        mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/x-PII", "SUclicked")
        mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003", 2)
        Cancel = False
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (SSNbtnPress = 3) Then
        mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003", 2)
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you desire is to check whether the item being sent corresponds to the item open at the time of sending, you need to look into the *ActiveInspector*.

You can access the active inspector through your reference variable to the Outlook application, and you can access the Application variable through the item itself.

Once referencing the ActiveInspector, you can get its CurrentItem and compare this to the item being sent, e.g.

```
Dim isItemBeingSentCurrent As Boolean = mailItem.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem Is mailItem
```

Comment: Simply putting this line in throws an exception, but not in the VS debugger, which is weird, rather on load to Outlook it says it can't be found.

Comment: Got it to load, getting this exception now: Operator '=' is not defined for type 'MailItem' and type 'MailItem'.

Comment: Oh, I got VB.NET and VBA mixed up in my reply, as I only tested it in VBA. I have edited the response.

Comment: That and mailItem.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem Is mailItem) works ( I think lol). But I still have the problem where if I click cancel (cancel=True) for this particular email. Even if I open a new one it still sending that cancel=true command to a new window? Would I have to put an IF statement after the ITEM_SEND event to say If isItemBeingSendCurrent= True Then

Comment: Did I understand the wording of your post correctly when I assumed you want this handler (Item_Send) to escape if it does not handle the item currently open?

In that case you'd simply have to do something like this in the beginning of the method:
If(isItemBeingSentCurrent) Then Exit Sub

Comment: Correct, basically I have the email come up and if it detects a attachment or SSN in the body of the email(or subject) a form comes up asking them to encrypt/send, send unencrypted, or Cancel. The Cancel button is what is causing problems. If I click cancel, it goes back to the email and lets them change whatever, but if I open an email (even if i delete this first one) and click send, it acts as if it is still in the Cancel=True and doesn't send, just sits there and the only way I can send ANYTHING afterwards is if I go back to that original email and send it. Real bad.

Comment: I just made a similar setup with a form triggering on Item_Send that cancels the mail if I click a specific button, and I was unable to reproduce your issue with two mails open.

What is the scope of your 'SSNbtnPress' variable? I.e. where is it declared and when is it accessed?

Comment: Global Variable from a Custom Userform: Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SSNbtnPress = 2
        Close()


    End Sub

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to chat :-)

Well, then I rather suspect that there's an issue with the variable. The ItemSend handler is called for any separate item being sent, and the only way it is cancelled is if you set Cancel = True. The only line I see in your code doing that is if 'SSNbtnPress' is set to 3. Does the variable need to be globally scoped?

Comment: can we chat somewhere else

Comment: I showed you code from  the userform that upon button press sets the variable SSNBtnPress to equal 1,2, or 3. I then call that variable to the main Addin script

Answer (score 0):

I would think some property is stored from mail1 and not reset when sending other items. Therefore all further mails will not be send

Comment: That was exactly what my problem was, I had a IF statement that was left open and thus a global variable was left set for future emails. Bad! Putting an ELSE statement to Cancel=False Exit Sub, did the trick. Thanks to user "lol".

Comment: was a pleasure, I had exactly the same Problem once,  therefore it was an easy guess.